# How to add a bunch polygon(100-500) to googleMap(v2) at once and avoid stackOverflowerror?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2, stack-overflow

I'm trying to draw a bunch(100-500) polygons from database(sqlite) to map. I use AsyncTask to deal the process, but when my database includes more than 100 rows, my app will be stopped and get java.lang.StackOverflowError.

Is the problem at the "get polygon from database" or "add polygons to map"?

thanks for help!

follow is my code and log trace:

```
public class DataBaseToMap extends
    AsyncTask<Context, Void, HashMap<String, PolygonOptions>> {

private DBHelper dbHelper;
private HashMap<String, PolygonOptions> pos;

@Override
protected HashMap<String, PolygonOptions> doInBackground(Context... params) {

    Context context = params[0];
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    pos = new HashMap<String, PolygonOptions>();

    List<Layer> layers = dbHelper.getAllLayer();

    for (Layer l : layers) {
        if (l.getDisplay().equals("YES")) {
            String layerName = l.getLayerName();
            HashMap<String, PolygonOptions> pos1 = dbHelper
                    .getPolygon(layerName);
            pos.putAll(pos1);
        }
    }
    return pos;
}
```

}

```
private class GetPolygonFromDB extends DataBaseToMap {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog.show();
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, PolygonOptions> pos) {
        Iterator<String> iterator = pos.keySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) iterator.next();
            map.addPolygon(pos.get(key));
        }

        if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

```
07-03 09:20:45.229: E/AndroidRuntime(12426): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 16156
07-03 09:20:45.229: E/AndroidRuntime(12426): java.lang.StackOverflowError
07-03 09:20:45.229: E/AndroidRuntime(12426):    at oas.a(Unknown Source)
07-03 09:20:45.229: E/AndroidRuntime(12426):    at oas.a(Unknown Source)
07-03 09:20:45.229: E/AndroidRuntime(12426):    at oas.a(Unknown Source)
07-03 09:20:45.229: E/AndroidRuntime(12426):    at oas.a(Unknown Source)
07-03 09:20:45.229: E/AndroidRuntime(12426):    at oas.a(Unknown Source)
07-03 09:20:45.229: E/AndroidRuntime(12426):    at oas.a(Unknown Source)
and more......
```

Comment: you've to lay each polygon as overlay on mapview. Look at Overlay class.

Comment: Thanks for respond. But is mapView working only? I use MapFragment to place a map in this case.

Comment: before overlaying anything, check map view is working correctly or not? MapFragment should be fine for mapview.

Comment: #zIronManBox. I still have no idea. Do you have any examples show how should I do?

Comment: which one do you need now? Overlaying polygon? or Make mapview work?

Comment: #zIronManBox. Any examples for overlaying hundreds of polygons to map? Thanks.

Comment: This is a good start to look for:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912427/android-mapview-slows-after-drawing-too-much-polygon